# Could not find artifacts for ./Election from any sources

Tags: truffle, dapps, truffle-migration, ethereumj

I tried solutions provided in ethereum stack, but nothing worked for me.

My smart contract file:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract Election {

    string public candidate;

    function Eletion () public {
        candidate = "Candidate 1";
    }
}
```

Migration file:

```
var Election = artifacts.require("./Election.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Election);
};
```

Im getting the following Error

> Using network 'development'.
>
> Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
>
> C:\Users\jeevastella\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:59973
>   throw new Error("Could not find artifacts for " + import_path + " from
>   any sources");
>           ^ C:\Users\jeevastella\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:59973
>   throw new Error("Could not find artifacts for " + import_path + " from
>   any sources");   ^
>
> Error: Could not find artifacts for ./Election from any sources
>       at Resolver.require (C:\Users\jeevastella\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:59973:9)
>       at Object.require (C:\Users\jeevastella\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:69602:36)
>       at ResolverIntercept.require (C:\Users\jeevastella\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:197047:32)
>       at C:\Users\jeevastella\Desktop\election\migrations\2_deploy_contracts.js:1:26
>       at Script.runInContext (vm.js:107:20)
>       at Script.runInNewContext (vm.js:113:17)
>       at C:\Users\jeevastella\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:101639:14
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)

Comment: construcor name should be same as the contract name

Comment: It clearly states that it can't find the contract. So either it's not in the current directory or it has different filename.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you still need the answer, but I fixed it by editing the migration file require path. 
Change it to in your case 
`var Election = artifacts.require("Election")`
Then run migrate with --reset

Answer (score 1):

Do verify that the name of smart contract is same as mentioned in the migration file.