# Could not find artifacts for " + import_path + " from any sources

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration

I'm working through a Solidity course on Udemy.  I'm trying to run `migrate` on truffle.

Here's my code:

MyToken.sol

```
// contracts/GLDToken.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20("Testing Token", "TST") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
}
```

2_depoly_contracts.js

```
var MyToken = artifacts.require("MyToken");

module.exports = async function(deployer) {
    await deployer.deploy(MyToken, 1000000);

}
```

truffle-config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "client/src/contracts"),
  networks: {
    develop: {
      port: 8545
    }
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.8.0"
    }
  }

};
```

Here is the error I'm getting when running truffle:

```
2_deploy_contracts.js
=====================

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/459.bundled.js:27241
        throw new Error("Could not find artifacts for " + import_path + " from any sources");
        ^

Error: Could not find artifacts for MyToken from any sources
    at Resolver.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/resolver/dist/lib/resolver.js:60:1)
    at Object.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:172:1)
    at ResolverIntercept.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/ResolverIntercept.js:22:1)
    at /Users/macbookdbw/Dropbox/Personal/Solidity/TokenizeProject/migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js:1:25
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:144:12)
    at Script.runInNewContext (vm.js:149:17)
    at Object.file (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/require/require.js:94:1)
    at Migration._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:44:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at Migration.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:217:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:150:1)
    at Object.runFrom (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:110:1)
    at Object.runAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:114:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:79:1)
    at runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate/run.js:76:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate/run.js:44:1)
    at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:189:1)
```

I've looked at these questions and I think I'm employing these answers ([1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62663/could-not-find-artifacts-for-election-from-any-sources), [2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91887/error-could-not-find-artifacts-for-migrations-from-any-sources)) , but still no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This might be silly, but have you compiled your solidity file?

https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/compiling-contracts.html